# What steps are required to create an android native page to show from web view

Tags: java, android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am studying for the Worklight 6.0 certification, and was wondering what the correct answer
is to the following question posed in the tutorials.

What are the steps to create a native page?

- A. Create a new Java class, extend the activity.
- B. Create a new Java class, extend the activity, and add an activity declaration
  to the AndroidManifest.xml.
- C. Create a new Java class, extend the native page.
- D. Create a new Java class, extend the native page, and add a native page
  declaration to the AndroidManifest.xml.

The tutorial states that (a) above is all that is required, however, I believe the correct answer is (b).

Comment: What the **** is a native page? Do you mean NativeActivity from the NDK?

Comment: @StackOverflowException, you can read about native pages in Worklight here: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/06_04_Android_-_Using_native_pages_in_hybrid_applications.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Answer is b - Create a new Java class, extend the activity, and add an activity declaration to the AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Read [the relevant training module](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova) from the IBM Worklight Getting Started page.
(b) is the answer.

Which tutorial are you referring to?

Comment: I was using the Getting Started tutorials.

Comment: Those have a few questions at the end of each presentation, and that question is flagged with the answer that does NOT include the addition of the activity to the ANdroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Fixd. Will be online after the next round of updates to the material, soon.

Comment: @user3093360, if this answer helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.